# ExtJs:Initializing a global variable

Tags: extjs4

I have a global variable which needs to be initialized when the store is loaded and needs to use that value in another store as follows

```
var cp = 0;

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('Init', {
        singleton: true,
        cp: 0
    });

    Ext.define('loggedUserList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'id',
            'name'
        ]
    });

    loggedUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'loggedUserList',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: url+'/lochweb/loch/users/getLoggedUser',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'provider'
        },
        listeners: {
            load: function(loggedUser) {
                Init.cp = loggedUser.getAt(0).data.id;
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

I am using the value of cp in another url as follows: `url: url + '/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId=' + Init.cp,`

```
Ext.define('vocbList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            mapping: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'code',
            mapping: 'code'
        }
    ]
});

var vocabulary = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {             
    model: 'vocbList',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',                   
        url: url+'/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId='+Init.cp,                    
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Vocabulary'
        }
    }
});
```

but its value is still 0. I tried using(cp, Init.cp). How to assign its value form store so that it can be reused?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store loads data asynchronously, so you can't be sure that Init.cp will be initialized with a new value before the other store is been loaded.
Try with this:

```
var cp=0;

Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define('Init', {
    singleton: true,
    cp: 0
});

Ext.define('vocbList', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                { name: 'id', mapping: 'id' },
                { name: 'code', mapping: 'code' }

            ]
        });



    var vocabulary = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {             
        model: 'vocbList',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',                                   
            reader:  {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'Vocabulary'
            }
        }

Ext.define('loggedUserList', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: ['id','name']
            });

            loggedUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'loggedUserList',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : url+'/lochweb/loch/users/getLoggedUser',
                    reader: {
                     type: 'json',
                        root: 'provider'
                    }                   
                },
                listeners: {
                    load:function(loggedUser){
                        Init.cp = loggedUser.getAt(0).data.id;
                        vocabulary.getProxy().url = url+'/lochweb/loch/vocabulary/getVocabularyByProvider?providerId='+Init.cp;
                        vocabulary.load();
                    }
                }

            }); 
});
```

As you can see, you have to set the url of the vocabulary proxy dynamically when the first store is just loaded and then load the store.

Cyaz

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare `loggedUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    model: 'loggedUserList',
                    autoLoad: true,...}` with Init.cp is assigned with some data in load(). But you cannot confirm that Init.cp has actually had value at the time you declare variable `vocabulary` (i.e. maybe loggedUser has not yet fully been loaded). So it still be 0 in the url.

To confirm, you should move codes of `vocbList` and `vocabulary` into a function:

```
function vocabularyLoad() {
   Ext.define('vocbList', {...});
   var vocabulary = ...
}
```

and use the function this way in `loggedUser`:

```
loggedUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    listeners: {
         load:function(loggedUser){
              Init.cp = loggedUser.getAt(0).data.id;
              vocabularyLoad();
         }
    }
 });
```

But actually, this refactoring makes the assignment of `Init.cp` redundant because you can directly pass the value of `loggedUser.getAt(0).data.id` into the defined function.