# Extjs4. Restore previous filter result

Tags: extjs, extjs4, filtering, records

I have in a viewport a textfield that it is for searching purpose. I have also a store that holds the data from the search queries. When user conducts a search and if query has results the store is populated with records. Each time user makes a search the store is updating with the new records. It is likely that some queries will not return results. So, what I want is when the search query don,t return any results not to update the store but retain the last successful query results. How can I do that?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Hello, i haven't tried anything yet. I am reading to Sencha docs.

Comment: Reading docs is very good. When you will have some specific questions we will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable and update it conditionally.

check this post [ExtJs:Initializing a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468734/extjsinitializing-a-global-variable)

Start your coding and ask specific questions coming on your way.